# Получить иерархичный объект из SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Как получить объект из SQL вида:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Guid qid { get; set; }
    public string qtitle { get; set; }
    public Group[] groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int gid { get; set; }
    public string gtitle { get; set; }
    public Answer[] answers { get; set; }

}

public class Answer
{
    public int aid { get; set; }
    public string atitle { get; set; }
}
```

Пытаюсь так:

```
WITH Recursive (Id, ParentId, Title, DocumentId)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Title, DocumentId
    FROM dbo.doc_MarketingTemplate t
    WHERE t.DocumentId='2A973C7F-3B28-47F3-98C9-6E921CDD1CF0' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.Id, t.ParentId, t.Title, t.DocumentId
    FROM dbo.doc_MarketingTemplate t
        JOIN Recursive r ON t.ParentId = r.Id
)
SELECT Id, ParentId, Title, DocumentId
FROM Recursive r
```

Comment: qid хранится в одной таблице, группы и ответы во второй, элементы с группами связаны полем ParentId, таблицы связаны по GUID qid

Comment: От SQL-сервера можно получить только набор записей. Трансформировать записи в объект придётся клиентскому приложению.

Comment: @Alex, у вас ORM или обычный ADO.NET?

Comment: Нужно получить Dapperом

Comment: @Alex, в таком случае лучше получить сначала из RootObject, а потом коллекцию из второй таблицы по ID родителя

Comment: А как получить коллекцию с вложенным массивом?

Comment: Обновил код выше, но что то не так

Comment: @Alex, я в ваших модельных классах никакой рекурсии не вижу, почему вы пишете рекурсивный запрос?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, если не рекурсией то как?

Comment: @Alex, когда обращаетесь к кому-то в комментарии - указывайте символ "@" и ник пользователя, тогда он получит уведомление и быстрее отреагирует, иначе приходится специально заходить в топик и смотреть, не появился ли комментарий.

Comment: По поводу вопроса: делаете первый запрос `select * from table1 where id = :id` и маппите его на свой объект, делаете второй запрос `select * from table2 where parentid = :id`, маппите на коллекцию элементов и добавляете эту коллекцию в свой первый объект

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить xml от скуль-сервера, соответствующий вашей структуре, используя FOR XML  и PATH , вот так - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb510462(v=sql.120).aspx
А на клиенте десериализовать в вашу модель любым XML-сериализатором.
Но вообще вам правильно сказали - наполняйте модели последовательными селектами - для RootObject, Group и Answer стройте свои мапперы